# Upload files to multiple buckets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I create a rails application for uploading files through carrierwave to S3 bucket,
I uploaded them to one bucket and I want to upload them to two buckets and regions at the same time .
How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Multiple uploads increase the possibility of connection issues. If the second upload ist just for backup reasons, you might want to consider AWS S3 settings that deal exactly with this (backup, versioning, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an upload method and send your bucket name as an argument. A quick and dirty version would look something like:

```
def upload_file(specific_bucket = nil)
  unless specific_bucket  
    BUCKET_LIST.each do |bucket|
      # send file to bucket
    end
  else
    # upload to specific_bucket
  end
end
```

Store your bucket list in an appropriate location

```
BUCKET_LIST = [bucket_name_one, bucket_name_two]
```